# Performing dynamic request validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, validation

I have an object from mongodb like this

```
{
  "_id": "588c5c0d709d11e2aa0da250",
  "fields": [
    {
      "type": "text",
      "required": true,
      "placeholder": "Food name",
      "name": "name",
      "label": "Name",
      "order": 1
    },
    {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true,
      "placeholder": "Item price",
      "name": "price",
      "label": "Price",
      "order": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Which basically represents a form, i use the fields array to generate a form on the frontend and also do validation on the frontend, however am struggling with validating the submitted data server-side.
A request looks like this

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "price",
            "value": 17000
        }
    ]
}
```

Based on form fields defined in the object, the name field is missing. I have validation function setup

```
validate: (req, fields) => {
        var errors = [];
        if(!req.data) {
            errors.push({field: 'data', message: 'data field is required'})
        }
        else {
            _.each(fields, (f) => {
                if(f.required) {
                    _.each(req.data, (d) => {
                        if(typeof d[f.name] == "undefined") {
                            errors.push({field: f.name, message: "field is required" })
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        }

        return errors;
    }
```

However my method returns an error message for field that is present in the request.

```
[
    {
      "field": "price",
      "message": "field is required"
    }
  ]
```

I'm pretty sure my validation method is missing something, i just not quite sure what it is. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out

```
'use strict';

const _ = require('lodash');

let getRequiredFields = (fields) => {
    return fields
        .filter((f) => { return f.required == true })
        .map((f) => {
            return f.name;
        })
}

module.exports = {
    validate: (req, fields) => {
        let errors = [];
        if(!req.data) {
            errors.push({field: 'data', message: 'data field is required'})
        }
        else {
          let requiredFields = getRequiredFields(fields); 
          _.each(requiredFields, (f) => {
              if(!req.data.hasOwnProperty(f)) {
                  errors.push({
                      field: f,
                      message: 'field is required'
                  })
              }
          })
        }

        return errors;
    }
}
```